# Excel to Datagridview filter and location

Tags: c#, excel, forms, winforms, datagridview

I have imported an Excel spreadsheet into a datagridview for a Windows Form Application in C#. However I need to then filter the data by 2 conditions, these conditions are that 2 separate text boxes are equal to a certain value inputted by the user. I have attached my code and screenshot of my form. I need the filter to go in the "btnFetch" click event: i.stack.imgur.com/GA6SX.png

I need the data to be filtered by those codes in the data, e.g) Departure Airport = BIKF and Arrival Airport = to EGGW and it will only bring those rows up.

Also is there a way that I can make it so the user selects the location of the Excel file to import through a pop-up window? 
Code:

```
public class frmMain : Form{
    public frmMain()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void frmMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dg1.Visible = true;
        pb1.ImageLocation = “C:/…abc.png;
        pb1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;
    }
    private void btnOpen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection();
        conn.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source = C:….abc.xlsx” + @";Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0; HDR=Yes; IMEX=1; ImportMixedTypes=Text;TypeGuessRows=0""";

        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]",conn);

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        OleDbDataAdapter adpt = new OleDbDataAdapter(command);
        adpt.Fill(ds);

        dg1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
    }
    private void btnFetch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void btnClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtDepAir.Text = "";`enter code here`
        txtDestAir.Text = "";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to let the user choose the excel file?

Yes there is a way,just use an `OpenFileDialog`.

```
using (OpenFileDialog OFPD = new OpenFileDialog)
{
if (OPD.ShowDialog== DialogResult.OK) {
    OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection("DataSource =" + OPD.FileName + "......");
  {

   }}}
```

**TIP :** If retrieved a single table,a dataset is useless.

> filter the data by 2 conditions, these conditions are that 2 separate text boxes

You can do that too.As suggested above,either you use a `DataTable` only or a `DataReader`.

**Filter using DataTable**

```
using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$] WHERE [ONE COLUMN NAME]=@col1 AND [2nd COLUMN NAME]=@col2",conn)
 {
 command.Parameters.Add("@col1",OledbType.VarChar).Value = txtbx1.Text;
 command.Parameters.Add("@col2",OledbType.VarChar).Value = txtbx2.Text;
 DataTable dt = new DataTable;
 SqlDataAdapter ada = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
 ada.Fill(dt)
 DataGrdView1.DataSource = dt;
 }}
```

**Filter using dataReader**

```
 using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$] WHERE [ONE COLUMN NAME]=@col1 AND [2nd COLUMN NAME]=@col2",conn)
 {
 command.Parameters.Add("@col1",OledbType.VarChar).Value = txtbx1.Text;
 command.Parameters.Add("@col2",OledbType.VarChar).Value = txtbx2.Text;
 SqlDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader;
 DataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
 while (dr.read)
 {
  DataGridViewRow row =  (DataGridViewRow)yourDataGridView.Rows[0].Clone();
  row.Cells[0].Value = "XYZ";
  row.Cells[1].Value = 50.2;
  DataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
  }}}
```

Hope this helps you :)

Comment: using (OpenFileDialog OPD = new OpenFileDialog()) would be so much better. Always dispose any object that inherites from idisposable !!!

Comment: @GuidoG , thanks for pointing out ... If u find the answer useful, i'll be glad if u upvote it :)

Comment: Thanks, but I get an error when using "OFPD.DialogResult", it says 'OpenFileDialog' does not contain a definition for 'DialogResult'. @zackraiyan

Comment: please recheck my answer

Comment: Thanks a lot that has worked, however the only error I get now is that " command.Parameters.Add("@col1",OledbType.VarChar).Value = txtbx1.Text;" It gives an error for "OledbType does not exist in the current context". Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Are u sure you have `System.Data.OleDb` referenced ? if no then just use `System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType`

Comment: I do have System.Data.OleDb referenced and when I add System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataType it does not recognise it.

Comment: *System.Data.OleDb.oleDbType

Comment: Ah no worries I have fixed it, it needs to be OleDbType. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: your getting close, there are still other objects in your code that can be put into a using.

Comment: @GuidoG,take a look at my code again,if it's ok, i'll be glad if u upvote :)

Comment: @GuidoG , thanks :) Always love to help :) ... Can i ask u somethig ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167864/discussion-between-zack-raiyan-and-guidog).